# Using Azure iOS toolkit SDK on background thread

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, azure-storage

I have a persistent queue which executes tasks on a background thread. This is useful for situations where a user is offline, etc and tasks need to persist until completed. Tasks are queued up and then executed until completed successfully. This queue runs on a background thread. Works great.

My issue is that when I try and make a call to the Windows Azure iOS toolkit from the background thread it never returns. Whether using the delegate pattern or block pattern implementations. So for example:

```
[storageClient fetchBlobContainerNamed:@"myContainer" withCompletionHandler:^(WABlobContainer *container, NSError *error) {
    ....
}];
```

the completion handler will never be called. I have confirmed that Azure toolkit does not like being called on a background thread. The same code executes fine when it is shunted over to the main thread. However this breaks my whole persistent task queue.

Any ideas on how to get Azure toolkit SDK to run from a background thread?

Comment: No. The command executes fine (the HTTP GET request is sent to the server and logged). It just doesn't come back.

Comment: If you have access to the internals of the framework (source files), start setting up some Breakpoints!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please file a bug [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/issues) with the simplest possible repro? We will investigate.

Comment: That link goes to the Azure Mobile Service repository. However the issue was with the Azure iOS Toolkit. So I assume I should post the issue to the Toolkit repository?

Comment: Issue has been logged: https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Toolkits/wa-toolkit-ios/issues/50